# Kendo dropdownlist trigger change event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to set the value of my Kendo dropdownList using the code below and expecting the "Change" event to be raise but it doesn't. Can someone please help.

Added additional Code as requested.

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
     <select id="serviceAccounts"
             kendo-drop-down-list
             k-ng-model="vm.customer.serviceAccountId"
             k-value-primitive="true"
             k-options="vm.setServiceAccountOptions" style="width: 100%">
     </select>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I'm afraid that when you run `setServiceAccountOptions()` the widget isn't initialized yet. Can you post your full code ?

Comment: setServiceAccountOptions() calling when data is available. i have added code for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#serviceAccounts").trigger("change");
```

Does not trigger the "change" event of the Kendo DropDownList because

```
$("#serviceAccounts")
```

Is not your Kendo DropDownList...it is just a jQuery selector.

You need to get a reference to the actual DropDownList before you can trigger one of its events, i.e.:

```
var dropDownList = $("#serviceAccounts").getKendoDropDownList();
dropDownList.trigger("change");
```

Example showing difference between selector.trigger() and dropdownlist.trigger():
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/UxiLo

Example showing how to trigger the change event using angular widget reference instead of jQuery widget reference:
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/IToFI

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! But,  $("#serviceAccounts").getKendoDropDownList(); is coming "undefined".

Comment: You must still be trying to trigger the event *during* initialization instead of *after*...you can't get the reference to the widget until kendo has finished initializing it.  During setServiceAccountOptions()(where you were trying to trigger the event before your edit), the widget does not exist yet as DontVoteMeDown indicated, since that is right in the middle of the initialization code.  So, you need to do 2 things: use the correct syntax to get a reference to the widget AND wait until the widget is finished initializing before trying to reference it.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your answer